# How to check whether a document field, of type array, already contains a value through Firestore rules?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Given the document type:

```
interface Post {
  content: string;
  sharedBy: Array<string>;
}
```

The constraint to be enforced is to allow users to concatenate their `uid` to the `sharedBy` array exactly once.

Furthermore, in my unit tests, a document is created where `post.sharedBy` is `[]` initially. Hence the first update succeeds and the value of `sharedBy` becomes `['1']` as confirmed by a query below (`'1'` is a test `uid`).

Afterwards, the exact same update is performed, however instead of failing, it too succeeds.

Given the following rules:

```
function canShare() {
  return !resource.data.sharedBy.hasAny([request.auth.uid]); // also attempted with `hasAll`
}

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if false;
    }
    match /posts/{postId} {
      allow read: if true;
      allow write: if request.auth != null && canShare();
    }
  }
}
```

Why does the, above mentioned, second update succeed instead of failing?

**EDIT**

The following are the contents of the test file:

```
import {
  initializeTestApp,
  initializeAdminApp,
  assertSucceeds,
  assertFails,
} from '@firebase/testing';

const projectId = 'projectId';
const myId = '1';
const myAuth = { uid: myId };

const getFirestore = (auth?: typeof myAuth) =>
  initializeTestApp({
    auth,
    projectId,
  }).firestore();

const getAdminFirestore = () =>
  initializeAdminApp({
    projectId,
  }).firestore();

const myPost = {
  content:
    'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Minus, doloribus praesentium nulla pariatur esse laborum a in obcaecati expedita recusandae.',
  sharedBy: [],
};

const getMyPost = () => getAdminFirestore().collection('posts').add(myPost);

describe('App tests', () => {
  test("user can increase any post's share count by 1 only once", async () => {
    const db = getFirestore(myAuth);

    const { id } = await getMyPost();

    console.log((await db.collection('posts').doc(id).get()).data()!.sharedBy); // []

    await assertSucceeds(
      db
        .collection('posts')
        .doc(id)
        .update({ sharedBy: [myId] }),
    );
    console.log((await db.collection('posts').doc(id).get()).data()!.sharedBy); // ['1']
    await assertFails(
      // error
      db
        .collection('posts')
        .doc(id)
        .update({ sharedBy: [myId] }),
    );
  });
});
```

Comment: Is your function really declared at the top level of the file, outside of service block? I think also it might be helpful if you show the matching code.  Rules only make sense when paired with code that should trigger the rules.

Comment: Yes the function is outside the service block. Absolutely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is currently any way in security rules to enforce that an array only contains unique values. While the clients can ensure that this is the case by using the `array-union` operator, a malicious client can add a duplicate entry.

The only way to ensure uniqueness in Firestore is to ensure the values are the keys. So you could make `sharedBy` a map, where the key is the UID of the user. That way you're guaranteed that each UID is present only once, as the keys in a map are by definition unique.

Another option is to stored the `sharedBy` elements in a subcollection, and there too use the UID as the document ID. That way, once again, the system already ensures that the IDs are unique.

A final option is to only allow updating of the `sharedBy` array through a Cloud Function, or some other trusted process, where your code can enforce this business rule.

Comment: Not ideal, but it is what it is. Using a map is similar and also suits the use case. Thanks!

Comment: Well, you can convert the List to a Set (which must only contain unique values), the compare their sizes to see if there is a duplicate. Both list and set have a size method.

Comment: On that note, I was wondering whether there's a way to create a `set` client side, since it is possible to validate `request.resource.data.sharedBy is set` through rules. Nevertheless, it's possible to convert the list and check `request.resource.data.sharedBy.size() == request.resource.data.sharedBy.toSet().size()`. The only thing left is to confirm that the user hasn't modified the set beyond adding their email, which, I hope, can be accomplished with `request.resource.data.sharedBy.hasOnly(resource.data.sharedBy.concat([request.auth.uid]))`.

Comment: Ended by dropping the initially thought out restriction of users only being able to concatenate their `uid` if it's not already present, and implementing sharedBy as `Record<string, true | undefined>` and checking for `request.resource.data.sharedBy[request.auth.uid] == true && request.resource.data.sharedBy.keys().size() == 1`.

Comment: Ooh, that's a good one Doug. I didn't think of that. It might be worth posting that as a separate answer, as it seems to be a solution that is closer to the question.